# Ruby - Checking if multiple values appear anywhere in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am making a text game and when you get to the final door, it is locked. You need three items (Strings in an array) to pass.

So I'm trying to make an if statement to see if your inventory (which can carry the three items, as well as others) contains these specific three items located anywhere.

```
array1 = ["key1", "key2", "key3", "sword", "dagger"]
array2 = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]

if array1.include? array2
  puts "it does"
else
  puts "it doesn't"
end
```

I've tried things like using any and include, but I can't come up with a simple solution on how I would do this as my tests have shown unexpected results.

Thanks.

Comment: @CarySwoveland gave you an excellent answer but have you considered storing inventory in a `Hash` e.g. `inventory = {keys: ["key1","key2","key3"],weapons: ["sword","dagger"]}` then it would be as simple as `inventory[:keys] == array2`. This would also add to in game functionality by classifying things like keys, weapons, and many more items.

Comment: @engineersmnky - Good idea! I haven't gotten to the hash part of the learning path, so I will definitely check that out, it seems like a better way to go. Also, I made it that in the story, I took out the weapons part, so it solely relies on items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array intersection:

```
array1 = ["key1", "key2", "key3", "sword", "dagger"]
array2 = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]

puts (array1 & array2 == array2) ? "it does" : "it doesn't"
  #=> "it does"

array2 = ["key1", "key2", "cat"]
puts (array1 & array2 == array2) ? "it does" : "it doesn't"
  #=> "it doesn't"
```

or difference:

```
puts (array2 - array1).empty? ? "it does" : "it doesn't"
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I used this method and implemented it. Now they can get through the door with the items, but rejected if they don't. Also I have a bit more array work to do :)